# Import Testcase in Testlink 1.9.9 from xlx format

Tags: testcase, testlink

I have to import my testcases which is in Excel into Testlink.How can I do it.Please help me out of this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's a decent macro available here: http://testlink-import.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/test-link-import.html

It'll output an xml file but you'll probably find it doesn't import without some tweaking.  I found it necessary to remove the `<testsuite>` tags and to add a `<testcases>` wrapper.

Also, if you add extra custom fields, you may find extra `<customfields>` tags.

I recommend running the macro with just one row of data and making sure you can import that first, then trying to do it in bulk.  I still ended up with 1 record that just wouldn't import and I never got to the bottom of it, but the process was quicker overall than manually entering 190 test cases.